# Trouble with && operator

Tags: java, if-statement

In the following code the `&&` within the if else statement  is giving a syntax error and i'm unsure how to solve it. Can anyone offer a solution?

```
//Importing scanner
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Credithistory {

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        //Stating scanner gets its input from console
        Scanner scanner= new Scanner (System.in);           
        //declaring int and boolean         
        int age;
        boolean goodCreditHistory;          
        System.out.println("Please enter your age... ");
        age= scanner.nextInt();         
        System.out.println("Do you have a good credit history (true or flase)?");
        goodCreditHistory= scanner.nextBoolean();           
        if  (age>=18) && ( goodCreditHistory== true){ // <-------------- Error   
            System.out.println("You have got a credit card!");              
        } else 
            System.out.println ("Sorry you are not eligible for a credit card.");
    }       
}
```

Comment: It's redundant to write `== true` in `if` statements. Possible issue that could happen is assigning by mistake instead of comparing.. So just write `if(something)` instead of `if(something == true)`.

Comment: The answers that don't have parentheses around the first condition, that is, (age >= 18), are taking advantage of the operator precedence. Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html . The >= has a higher precedence than &&, so it will be evaluated first, even without the parentheses.

Answer (score 14):

This is because of how you put the parentheses. The `if` statement is composed of two parentheses already, so you have to write you statement as

```
if ((age>=18) && (goodCreditHistory == true))
```

instead of

```
if (age>=18) && (goodCreditHistory == true)
```

since the second part of your statement (`&& (goodCreditHistory == true)`) is being parsed as if it was part of the `if` body.

You may write this statement in a more concise way as

```
if(age >= 18 && goodCreditHistory)
```

the extra parentheses are not needed. `== true` statement is also redundant.

Comment: Note that you use redundant parentheses here.

Comment: @AdamArold Yep, they're not really necessary. The `== true` statement is also redundant. I just copied OP code.

Answer (score 6):

Correct syntax is

```
   if  (age>=18 && goodCreditHistory){

}
```

Remove unnecessary parentheses. And also you need not to write

```
goodCreditHistory== true
```

since it is already a  `boolean`.

Answer (score 2):

In Java the *entire condition* for an `if` statement has to be contained within parentheses, so it should be:

```
if ((age>=18) && (goodCreditHistory== true)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Put both statements in one set of parentheses:

```
if (age>=18 && goodCreditHistory== true) {
    System.out.println("You have got a credit card!");
}
```